# how can i get the id from edit modal to be use as a parameter on the kendodropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem on my kendodropdown list on my edit modal..it cant get the id that needed to be its parameter on the edit modal..

heres my cshtml or view:

```
<div class="infoHeader">
        Worker Availability</div>
<div class="main">
    <input type="hidden" id="availabilityId" name="workerId" value="@workerId" />
    <input type="hidden" id="posSelect" name="posSelect" value="@posSelect" />
     <input type="hidden" id="hiddenUser" name="hiddenUser" value="@userId" />

    <div>
        <table id="availabilityGrid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 50px">
                    </th>
                    <th style='text-align: center;'>
                        Available Day
                    </th>
                    <th style='text-align: center;'>
                        Start Time
                    </th>
                    <th style='text-align: center;'>
                        End Time
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      <div id="modalEditWindow">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("hiremodal", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "workerindexForm" }))
    {

       <div class="main">
                   <input id="ddlWorker" name="ddlWorker" class:"validate[required] inputLong" style="width: 250px;"  required value="@ddlWorker2" />
                      <input type="hidden" id="availabilityIds" name="availabilityIds" />
       </div>
        <input type="submit" id="btnSaveContact" class="styledButton" value="Save" />
        <button id="btnConfirmEditNo" class="styledButton">
            No</button>



    }
</div>
    </div>
    <script id="availabilityTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
<tr class='k-alt'> 
 <td>
     <a href="/Worker/ViewProfilePage" id="btnEdit${ID}" class="k-button" style="text-decoration: none;">Hire</a>

         <input type="hidden" id="availabilityIds${ ID }" name="availabilityIds" value="${ ID }" />
         <input type="hidden" id="positionSelected${ PositionSelected }" name="positionSelected " value="${ PositionSelected  }" />
       <input type="hidden" id="workerId${ Worker_ID }" name="workerId" value="${ Worker_ID }" />

       <input type="hidden" id="posCode ${ posCode }" name="posCode" value="${ posCode }" />
       <input type="hidden" id="des${ des }" name="des" value="${ des }" />
    </td>       
    <td>
        ${AvailableDay} 
        <input type="hidden" id="dllEditAvailableDay${ ID }" name="dllEditAvailableDay" value="${ AvailableDay }" />               
    </td>   
      <td>      
      ${StartTime}
        <input type="hidden" id="editTpStartTime${ ID }" name="editTpStartTime" value="${ StartTime }" />  
    </td>
      <td>    
      ${EndTime}
         <input type="hidden" id="editTpEndTime${ ID }" name="editTpEndTime" value="${ EndTime }" />     
    </td>

</tr>
    </script>
```

heres my jquery:

```
        });'
```

for my jQuery grid and edit modal:

```
   var availabilityId = $("#availabilityId").val()
            $("#availabilityGrid").kendoGrid({
                scrollable: false,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: '/Worker/SortedWorkerAvail?availabilityId=' + availabilityId + '&positionSelected=' + positionSelected,
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST"
                        }
                    },
                    change: function (e) {
                        $(window.location.hash).click();
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#availabilityTemplate").html().replace('k-alt', '')),
                altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#availabilityTemplate").html())
            });


            var educationId = $("#educationId").val()
            // create modal pop up for delete confirmation
            editwnd = $("#modalEditWindow").kendoWindow({
                title: "Hire Worker",
                modal: true,
                visible: false,
                resizable: false,
                width: 600
            }).data("kendoWindow");

            $("[id^='btnEdit']").live("click", function (e) {



                // get the object in the scope

                var obj = $(this);
                var row = obj.closest("tr").find("input[name=availabilityIds]").val();
                $('#availabilityIds').attr('value', row);
                alert(row);
                // prevent to continue to default action
                e.preventDefault();
                editwnd.center().open();


// dropdown
                var userId = $("#hiddenUser").val();
                var posSelect = $("#posSelect").val();
                $("#ddlWorker").kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "Day_LookID",
                    dataValueField: "ID",
                    autoBind: false,


                    optionLabel: {
                        Day_LookID: "--- Please Select Position ---",
                        ID: ""

                    },
                    // define custom template
                    template:

    '#if(data.Day_LookID) {#<p>${ data.Day_LookID }</p>#}#' +
    '#if(data.StartTime && data.EndTime) {#<p>${ data.StartTime } - ${ data.EndTime }</p>#}#',

                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: '/Worker/LoadShiftDropdownList?userId=' + userId + '&posSelect=' + posSelect + '&availabilityIds=' + availabilityIds,
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "POST"

                            }
                        }
                    }


                });

                var dropdownlist = $("#ddlWorker").data("kendoDropDownList");

                dropdownlist.list.width(250);

            });
```

the hidden ID in the edit modal named availabilityIds is the Id that i want to make a parameter for my dropdown

sorry for the long code paste above.. i just cant move on with this error
thanks for those who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey have you tried with this code:

```
 var id = $('#availabilityId')[0].value;
```